# Is every convergent sequence in $L^1$ dominated?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This looks very obvious, but I can't prove it, and google is not helping (I also can't find any explicit mention to this in my textbook). I want to prove that, given a measure space $\left(X,\mathcal M,\mu\right)$, and given a sequence $f_n$ in $L^1\left(\mu\right)$ that converges in the $L^1$ metric, there is a dominating function $g\in L^1$ such that $\left|f_n\right|\leq g$ almost-everywhere.

I've tried constructing this $g$ function as the $\sup$ of the $f_n$s, or as the $\limsup$, or as the $\limsup$ plus a constant. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Is $f$ the limit of the functions $f_n$ ($f_n \to f$ in $L^1$)? If so, simply consider $g = |f|$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but I mistyped that: it should be $|f_n|\leq g$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample is $$f_n (x)= 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\log n & \mbox{if } x \in [H_n, H_{n+1}] \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
where $H_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}$ is the $n$-th harmonic number.

Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^1$, but they cannot be dominated.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that this sequence converges in $L^1$

Comment: Oh ok, $\log n/n\to 0$.

Comment: It is obvious since $\int |f_n| = \frac{\log n}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no if we're talking about $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$. Consider $$ f_n := n \cdot \chi_{[n,n+ 1/n^2]}(x)$$ Then we have $\|f_n\| = \frac{1}{n}$, so $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{1}$, but you cannot find a function such that $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

We can now easily determine the "smallest" function satisfying $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by defining

$$g (x)= 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
n & \mbox{if } x \in [n, n + \frac{1}{n^2}] \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{matrix}
\right. $$

Then $$\|g\| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|f_n \| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

Comment: Actually, in this example $g=\sup f_n$ works, because $\int g = \sum_n (2n+1)/n^2(n+1)^2$.

Comment: I edited it to make it work.